# How to anonymize application that not support proxy by using Tor on Windows?

Tags: configuration, windows, proxy

I just want to let all my network traffic go through Tor and I saw someone did it on Linux, but I've never seen this on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out [Proxifier](https://www.proxifier.com) which allows you to pass an executable's traffic through any SOCKS proxy.
you can set it to proxy all your traffic.